# Jupyter notebook not opening from Centos 7

Tags: python, centos, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I have recently installed jupyter notebook on Centos 7. I have been trying to get it launched on my browser from past 2 days and have tried every answer on stack overflow. It stopped showing " No web browser found " when i type it on the command terminal. But when i copy and paste the link onto the google chrome browser it's showing, This site can't be reached. 
How will i resolve this issue?

Comment: Did you copy the full link(including its token)?

Comment: Can you elaborate your problem with more details?

Answer (score 0):

If you follow carefully the instructions on this post, you'll solve your problem.
I went through the same situation and followed these steps.

https://techknight.eu/2016/01/03/setup-jupyter-notebook-centosrhel-7/

The key is to :

- Modify the configuration .py file with your desired values (specially the IP on wich the notebook will run).
- Allow the port you're gonna use throug the CentOS firewall

In any case, if you break the configuration and you need a fresh start, you can always do:

```
jupyter notebook --generate-config
```

And the file will regenerate with default values.

Good Luck